# IIS url resolving

Tags: iis

does company1.web.com.uk resolve to web.com.uk? or one has to configure this with the DNS server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure it on both DNS server and IIS web site.

You may wish to configure [DNS wildcard record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) to point all subdomains (e.g. company1.web.com.uk, company2.web.com.uk, www.web.com.uk etc.) to the same IP address as web.com.uk.